# What is the correct procedure for rosbag *.active if it is just not closed properly?

Tags: rosbag, ros-noetic

If there is a rosbag *.bag.active instead of *.bag, then according to the documentation and some answers in ROS answers, one should do both:

1. rosbag reindex
2. rosbag fix

But if the most likely cause was just not closing the recording properly and nothing else is probably wrong with the bag, are those 2 steps really necessary? Is there a simpler way to properly close a bag if there is no other issues?

E.g. large >100GB bags can take a while to reindex. And `rosbag fix` results in an error, requiring a bag migration rules file (.bmr) which is not present in some ros packages. When reading about `rosbag fix` and from there, for more explanation, about `rosbag migration`, it really seems like an unnecessary step for a inexperienced bag fix user.

EDIT: I also tried `rosbag fix -n` instead but still results in requiring the rules file. Is is correct to just use `rosbag fix --force`?

Thanks for your help to explain and make it more understandable in a simple case of not closing the recording.